# Is it fine to create a separate interface for call back function in MVP pattern

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-mvp

I am trying to create an app by using `MVP design pattern`. This is the first time i am using this pattern, thats the reason i am little concerned that either i am following the pattern correctly or not.

This is what i have done so far. I am not using `Dagger2`.

**Interface**

```
public interface MainActivityMVP {

    interface Model{
        void sendTokenToServer(MainActivityMVP.Presenter presenter);
    }

    interface View{
        boolean isPnTokenRegistered();
        void tokenUpdated();
        void tokenFailedToUpdate();
    }

    interface Presenter{
        void tokenUpdatedSuccessfully();
        void tokenAlreadyExists();
        void detachView();
    }
```

On `MainActivity`, I have created an instance of `Presenter` and `Model` and pass the `Model` object to `Presenter Constructor`

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainActivityMVP.View {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

            mainPresenter= new MainPresenter(this, new MainModel());
            mainPresenter.sendFCMTokenToServer();
        }
```

On Presenter I call `Model's` method to perform operation, and pass `presenter` reference to it.

**Presenter**

```
    public class MainPresenter implements MainActivityMVP.Presenter{

        MainActivityMVP.View view;
        MainActivityMVP.Model model;


        public MainPresenter(MainActivityMVP.View view, MainActivityMVP.Model model){
            this.view= view;
            this.model= model;
        }


        public void sendFCMTokenToServer() {
            model.sendTokenToServer(this);
        }

       @Override
       public void tokenUpdatedSuccessfully() {
         view.tokenUpdated();
       }

        @Override
        public void tokenAlreadyExists() {
          view.tokenFailedToUpdate();
        }
```

In Model, I create instance of `PreferenceManager` class that gets data from `SharedPreference`

```
public class MainModel implements MainActivityMVP.Model {

    PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;


    public MainModel(){
        preferencesHelper= new PreferencesHelper();
    }

 @Override
    public void sendTokenToServer(MainActivityMVP.Presenter presenter) {

        if (preferencesHelper.getNotificationSettings().isEmpty()) {
           //do stuff

           presenter.tokenUpdatedSuccessfully();
        }
  }
```

Now i have these questions.

- Is the above approach of implementing MVP pattern is fine, or i am
  missing something here.
- Is it fine if i add an other interface for call backs, or passing
  Presenter to model is better approach, as i have seen some example
  where they pass `interactor` reference to model.
- Is it necessary to create `Interactor Class` in MVP pattern
- Is it fine, and not against `MVP rule` if i create a separate
  interface for Repository,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers have different varieties of implementing MVP. Few people use interactors. Its is not compulsory to use interactors in MVP. I will suggest you below since you are in a starting stage.

```
 public interface MainView extends BaseView {
         boolean isPnTokenRegistered();
         void tokenUpdated();
         void tokenFailedToUpdate(); 
}
```

Then have your  basepresenter be like this

```
public interface BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> {

    void setView(V view);

    void destroyView();

    void destroy();
}
```

Now your MainPresenter

```
    public class MainPresenter implements BasePresenter<MainView>{

    MainView view;
    PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

   MainPresenter(){
        preferencesHelper= new PreferencesHelper();
   }

      @Override
      public void setView(MainView view) {
        this.view = view;
      }

      @Override
      public void destroyView() {
        this.view = null;
      }

      @Override
      public void destroy() {

      }

       public void sendFCMTokenToServer() {
            //Do whatever you want
        }

    }
```

Finally have your activity like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainView {

        MainPresenter mainPresenter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
            mainPresenter= new MainPresenter();
            mainPresenter.attachView(this)
            mainPresenter.sendFCMTokenToServer();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Raja for the detailed answer, Is `BaseView`  a marker interface?

Comment: BaseView is a general interface in which u can have ur  function declaration for Context get context (); error and retry function.